# Database Inter Relation between rows

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

There is an articles table which have fields as "article_id, title, year_published". Data in the table :

```
------------------------------------
article_id | title | year_published
------------------------------------ 
1|Mechanical Code|2012 
2|Mechanical Code|2015 
3|Contruction Workshop|2010 
4|Contruction Workshop|2012 
5|Contruction Workshop|2013 
6|Administrative Session I|2012 
7|Administrative Session II|2014 
8|Administrative Session III|2015
```

I need to find out same article which exists in multiple years.

I have queried my database to get result which grouped by title having count more than 1.

> select title, count(*) as total from articles group by articles having
>   total > 1;

But the issue is title names can differ and have version for the same article. Look at row 6-8 and above query will not get Administrative Session.

How to handle this type of relationship?

Comment: You need to fix the names.  A SQL query cannot do that for you, unless you can specify the rules you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I cannot change the title. I can create a new table. In that case how to handle this scenario?

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade : is there any table exists that specifies that `article_id` 6,7, & 8 belongs to same article group or share common attributes?

Comment: @seahawk No its not there. New table can do that. Admin will select that they are linked.

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade : Is there any fixed format for adding version..?

Comment: Ok, "New table can do that. Admin will select that they are linked." What does that table look like? Presumably they will say what article_id or titles are "the same article" or the same title. And you have to make clear to us what an "article" is vs what an article_id identifies and what it identifies uniquely, because .apparently it isn't articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another field 'articletype' of type integer for exemple, and set Administrative Session I, Administrative Session II and Administrative Session III to the same articletype.

```
--------------------------------------------------
article_id | title | year_published| articletype
--------------------------------------------------
1|Mechanical Code|2012|1
2|Mechanical Code|2015|1
3|Contruction Workshop|2010|2
4|Contruction Workshop|2012|2
5|Contruction Workshop|2013|2
6|Administrative Session I|2012|3
7|Administrative Session II|2014|3
8|Administrative Session III|2015|3
```

The SQL would be like this :

```
select title, count(*) as total from articles group by articletype  having total > 1;
```

Comment: I have used the same approach in little bit different manner.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the last part of the title *if you know it is a number*.  Something like this:

```
select (case when substring_index(title, ' ', -1) in ('I', 'II', 'III')
            then left(title, length(title) - locate(' ', reverse(title)))
            else title
       end) as basetitle, count(*) as total
from articles
group basetitle
having count(*) > 1;
```